# glsl: how exactly does passing parameters to shaders work?

Tags: parameters, attributes, glsl, shader

I'm trying to make a first custom shader for some deferred rendering, using OpenTK for c#. But I'm kinda lost when it comes to finding Information about how to pass parameters in general, and how to recieve them properly in the shader program. I've found some tutorials, but they always describe either the shader OR the code, rarly both (especially with higher glsl versions). Any Idea where I can get good information on this? (I can't even manage to draw a simple triangle, since I somehow can't get orthographic projection to work, I suspect I'm missing something with the matrices. I suspect I can get around that by skipping projection and drawing right to screen pixels)

```
#version 330 core
layout(location = 0) in vec3 vertexPosition_modelspace;
void main(){  
    gl_Position.xyz = vertexPosition_modelspace;
    gl_Position.w = 1.0;
 }

#version 330 core
out vec3 color;

void main(){
    color = vec3(1,0,0);
}
```

These shaders for example give me "Invalid Operation" when I try to Use the Program...

Comment: At a minimum, you need to understand how [vertex attributes](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Attributes) are used. You can't skip projection as such - geometry is clipped / projected to 3D 'device' coordinates. There's list of tutorials [here](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Getting_started#Tutorials_and_How_To_Guides).

Comment: If you're getting an invalid operation when "using" the program, you probably failed to link the program. Which either means one or more shaders failed to compile, or something went wrong during linking. Take a look at the output of `glGetShaderInfoLog (...)` for each shader and `glGetProgramInfoLog (...)` for the program after attempting to link the shaders together.

Comment: So do I understand it correctly, that using glsl in core mode REQUIRES me to know the exact name of all input vars of my vertex shader ?

Comment: Well, not necessarily the name. In new versions of OpenGL you can assign binding locations to vertex attributes explicitly in your vertex shader. You could call them whatever you wanted, as long as you know the attribute location in your software... the other way of accomplishing this is either to query the attribute location for a named attribute after linking, or binding the location before linking. Vertex attribute pointers are defined by attribute locations, which are assigned to named attributes; in compatibility GLSL functions like `glNormalPointer (...)` aliased to `gl_Normal`.